# before_filter to set primary key before create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using filter to set the primary key of an instance before saving it.

Here is my controller method:

```
class ReferencesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :set_primary_key, :only => [:create_sub_reference]

    def create_sub_reference    
    @reference = Reference.new(params[:reference])
    respond_to do |format|
    if @reference.save
      format.js
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Reference failed to save."
    end
    end
    end


    private

    def set_primary_key
    result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT REF_ID FROM SEQUENCES')
    inc_result = (result.fetch_row.first)
    self.REF_ID = inc_result
    end

    end 

end
```

I am getting the following error message in the log file when i click on the 'Save button':

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `REF_ID=' for #<ReferencesController:0xb69f4ca8>):
```

Thanks for any suggestion on this matter

Comment: here 'self' references to the controller not the @reference as you meant.

Comment: I even tried changing 'self.REF_ID' to '@reference.REF_ID' but in vain. I still get the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the REF_ID attribute - which I assume is a database column - on your Controller, not your model. That code will be invoked every time a web request for `ReferencesController` reaches your app.

Perhaps you wanted to move the logic to a `before_create` hook in the `References` model?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My method name is 'create_sub_reference', how do i use before_create for this particular method. I understand that before_create applies only to method called 'create'

Comment: `before_create` will be called before writing to the database whenever an object of the model on which it is defined is saved when it's new. It really does always act "before create" of a model instance.